# Player moves in Update() but not FixedUpdate() in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, c#-2.0

I made a car controller in unity to drive around. I've read FixedUpdate is better to use for physical objects instead of Update, but when I switch to Fixed update my car no longer drives. Does  anyone know why this might be? Thank so much you for any help you an provide!

```
    public float speed;
    public float turnSpeed;
    private RigidBody rb;

    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        Move();
        Turn();
    }

    void Move(){
        // moves the car
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W)){
            rb.AddRelativeForce(new Vector3(Vector3.forward.x, 0, Vector3.forward.z) * speed);
        } 
        else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S)){
            rb.AddRelativeForce(new Vector3(Vector3.forward.x, 0, Vector3.forward.z) * -speed);
        }
        // maintains forward velocity relative to car.
        Vector3 localVelocity = transform.InverseTransformDirection(rb.velocity);
        localVelocity.x = 0;
        rb.velocity = transform.TransformDirection(localVelocity);
    }

    void Turn(){
        // turns the car.
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D)){
            rb.AddRelativeTorque(Vector3.up * turnSpeed);
            Debug.Log("TURNING CAR");
        }
        else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A)){
            rb.AddRelativeTorque(-Vector3.up * turnSpeed);
            Debug.Log("TURNING CAR");
        }
```

Here's the code. Pressing W or S adds a force, pressing A or D adds a torque. When I try turning in FixedUpdate the console will write "TURNING CAR" as it should which shows that it's making past the AddRelativeTorque line, but it still won't turn so I'm not really sure what's going on. Thanks again, I really appreciate any help.

Comment: Have you tried increasing the force?  Since update runs much more frequently than fixed update, the accumulated force from update will be much more in the same time period than in fixed update.

Comment: @hijinxbassist `much more` is a bit exaggerated, though .. assume 60fps then Update is called 60 times while FixedUpdate by default 50 times a second .. that's not a huge difference ;) but yes in general you should take [`Time.deltaTime`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-deltaTime.html) into account in both and then shouldn't note a difference

Comment: Oh interesting. I will try that and get back soon

Comment: That worked!! thank you so much. Glad it was a simple fix.

Comment: Awesome, glad to hear it was a simple fix (those are the best!).  I posted my comment as an answer below.  Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Try increasing the force used.

Fixed update runs less frequently than update (using the default settings, in most scenarios).  Since the code is running much less frequently, less force is being accumulated over the same time period.

Consider a game running at 100fps.  The default fixed time step is 0.02s (50 frames per second).  Since update is running at 100fps, you have twice as much force being applied from update than would be applied from fixed update.

If you make your force value independent of the time since the last update happened, you will not need to worry about this.

For Update use myForceValue * Time.deltaTime.

For FixedUpdate use myForceValue * Time.fixedDeltaTime.